# Error while running docker build command from java code

Tags: java, docker, runtime

I am running docker build command from java using following code -

```
      Process p = new ProcessBuilder("docker","build","-f",Dockerfile,"--build-arg",some arguments,"-t","com.test:t-v16",".").start();
```

But ut gives me error -
Docker build requires exactly 1 arguments.

When googled, it was mentioned, there should be a dot (.) In the end of command. I have added it and still facing the issue. 
Same command works on command line.

Comment: Because your arguments are to `build` not `docker`. You need to read up on  how command line arguments work. Further, don't use `Runtime#exec` - [it's 2017](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Could you please show us what command has been executed finaly?

Comment: docker -f C:/test/Dockerfile --build-Arg Product_version=4.3 -t com.test:v-16 .

Comment: @Boris i have tried adding  dot before build arguments also.. still throwing same error

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to give a space before the "." in your String array.
Can you try and check it now.

```
String[] createBaseImage = {"docker","build","-f",Dockerfile,"--build-arg",some arguments,"-t","com.test:t-v16"," ."}:
```

Comment: @Disha Can you try without specifying the Dockerfile and running it from the directory where the Dockerfile is present.

Comment: This is not how the `String[]` of arguments to process execution works.